# Text Formatting: Using Enumeration

Tags: enumerate

I'm new to LaTex and I want to use `compactenum` from the `paralist` package for an enumeration. So I wrote the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{compactenum}[\mbox{FA-SWK-}1]
  \item Item one
  \item Item two
  \item Item three
  \item Item four
  \item Item five
  \item Item six
  \item Item seven
  \item Item eight
  \item Item nine
  \item Item ten
  \item Item eleven
  % and so on...
\end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```

Now I have the problem that the text from item 10 is out of alignment. Actually it looks like that:

```
FA-SWK-1 Item one
FA-SWK-2 Item two
...
FA-SWK-10 Item ten
```

But I want that it looks like this:

```
FA-SWK-1  Item one
FA-SWK-2  Item two
...
FA-SWK-10 Item ten
```

It is possible to add a null only for the first nine items or to change the spacing between the enumeration and the text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is `compactenum` the name of a package? Or is it a special `enumerate` list made with `enumitem`?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Are you using the `paralist` package.  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: `compactenum` is an environment from the `paralist` package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trick `paralist` into leaving more space for the number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\protected\def\double#1\double{\makebox[1em][l]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{compactenum}[\mbox{FA-SWK-}\double1\double]
  \item Item one
  \item Item two
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
\end{compactenum}

\end{document}
```

With `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\boxedarabic}[1]{\makebox[1em][l]{\arabic#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=FA-SWK-\boxedarabic*,nosep]
  \item Item one
  \item Item two
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the nicest method to resove my problem, but it works! I used your first solution with paralist

Comment: @riede The important thing is avoiding `1` being between braces. The trick above does it.

Comment: Personally I find the left alignment of the numbers 'weird', but any of the solutions (and the O.P.) have this feature

Answer (score 4):

A variant with `enumitem`, using the `widest` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength\mylabelwd
\settowidth{\mylabelwd}{FA-SWK-999}

\begin{document}

Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.
\begin{enumerate}[label=FA-SWK-\arabic*, widest =999, align=left, labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=\dimexpr\mylabelwd+\labelindent+\labelsep\relax, itemindent=*, noitemsep]
  \item Item one
  \item Item two
  \item Item three and so on. Item three and so on. Item three and so on. Item three and so on.
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
  \item Item three and so on
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution works for me when each item has only one row. Once there is a seconds row it doesn't work. The second row starts on the left side of the page and isn't arranged to the first row.

Comment: You didn't say in your post there are multilined items. I'll fix that in a moment.

Comment: @riede: I've modified my code. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\phantom` to create a character:

```
\begin{compactenum}[\text{FA-SWK-}1]
  \item \leavevmode\hphantom{0}one 
  \item \leavevmode\hphantom{0}two 
  \item \leavevmode\hphantom{0}three and so on 
  % Some other \item
  \item FA-SWK-10 ten
\end{compactenum}
```

It creates an invisible character that take the size of a as space. (can't show you the result due to the computer I use)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer wrong copy-paste thank you `;-)`

Comment: `\leavevmode\hphantom{0}` would be much better than `\phantom{a}`, for the simple reason that it works. Not because of `0` instead of `a`, but because `\phantom{...}` ***doesn't*** start a paragraph. And you shouldn't have `FA-SWK-1` and so on in the items.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution doen't really work for me. It looks like the invisible character will be added to the line before. But I don't know why.

Comment: `\leavevmode\hphantom{0}` works for the first row. Once the item has more than one row this solution doesn't help me because the second row has the old spacing.